# BeautifulSoup cannot find all <p> tags in html

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull articles' title, text, and user comments from websites using BeautifulSoup. I have managed to filter the first two but I'm having problems pulling the user comments. The code I have right now.

```
def extract_text(url):
    url_to_extract = url
    html = urllib.urlopen(url_to_extract).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()
    print 'Title and Publisher is:\n' + soup.title.string
    body_text = ''
    article = soup.findAll('p')
    for element in article:
        body_text += '\n' + ''.join(element.findAll(text=True))
    print body_text

def main():
   url_title = 'https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2016/oct/24/nicola-sturgeon-says-brexit-meeting-was-deeply-frustrating'
   extract_text(url_title)
```

I've checked the source code for this specific article in the main method, the user comments are available in < p> tags which should make them parsed by BeautifulSoup along with the article text, but it doesn't show. I tried to print all the beautifulsoup content by

```
print soup
```

It doesn't show the div where the user comments are supposed to be in. I've tried this on BBC and Guardian websites for now. I would be glad for any kind of help here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getArticle(url):
    url = 'http://www.bbc.com/news/business-34421804'
    result = requests.get(url)
    c = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c)

    article_text = ''
    article = soup.findAll('p')
    for element in article:
        article_text += '\n' + ''.join(element.findAll(text = True))
    return article_text
```